# Ruby on Rails - possible error in naming convention throughout a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, haml

I am making a login route and added this to the routes.rb `resources :sign_in`

I made a controller like this:

```
class Mobile::Sign_inController < ApplicationController
  layout "mobile/application"

  def get
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end


  end

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

end
```

and it seems to get routed correctly, but my view file which is located here:

```
/app/views/mobile/sign_in.html.haml
```

which just has 1  line for test purposes:

```
%strong{:class => "code", :id => "message"} Hello Signin!
```

But when I go to the url: http://m.cmply.local:8800/signin in the browser, the screen is totally white with nothing rendered in the browser.

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try changing the controller class name from `Mobile::Sign_inController` to `Mobile::SignInController`

Comment: @PinnyM just tried it, same result...I just see the totally white browser screen with nothing rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems here:

1. Your controller name should be `SignInsController`, not `Sign_inController`. Consider changing your name to `UserSessionsController` or similar, since that better reflects the *resource* it represents. You can still specify an alternate name for the URL (such as `sign_in`).
2. Why is your controller namespaced under `Mobile`? Your routes given don't reflect that, but you don't seem to have provided them all. The route should probably be under a `scope`:

   ```
   scope :module => "mobile" do
     resource :sign_in
   end
   ```
3. Since there is only "one" sign in, it should have its route declared `resource :sign_in`, and probably even `resource :sign_in, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]`, depending on what you want. This means that the `index` action no longer exists, and you probably want to replace it with the `new` action`.
4. There is no `get` action by default for RESTful resources, I'm not sure what you meant it to be, but it should be something else.